# Trouble with rspec test with a polymorphic class

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rspec, rspec2, polymorphic-associations

I'm using MongoMapper instead of ActiveRecord.

I have a User model and a Task model.
In the Task model, I have 2 attributes as follow:

- Owner
- Author

Both attributes are User references.

Here are the relations between the two models:

User.rb

```
has_many :tasks, :as => :owner
```

Taks.rb

```
belongs_to :owner, :class_name => "User", :polymorphic => true
```

I've used RSpec for writing test:
(@user is declared before)

```
it "should have many tasks" do
    another_user = Factory.create(:user, :email => Faker::Internet.email)

    task_1 = Factory.create(:task, :owner => another_user, :author => another_user)
    task_2 = Factory.create(:task, :owner => another_user, :author => @user)
    task_3 = Factory.create(:task, :owner => @user, :author => @user)

    another_user.tasks.size.should == 2
end
```

And here is the issue:

```
Failure/Error: another_user.tasks.size.should == 2
expected: 2
got: 3 (using ==)
```

However when I do the same in rails console, I get good results...

Here are the factories:

```
Factory.define :user do |u|
  u.first_name 'Test User'                          #
  u.username 'Test User'                            #
  u.surname 'TheTest'                               #
  u.email 'foo@foobar.com'                          #
  u.password 'please'                               #
  u.confirmed_at Time.now                           #
end

Factory.define :task do |u|
  u.author nil                                      #
  u.owner nil                                       #
  u.subjects []
  u.timeframe ""
  u.initially_placed_at nil
  u.label "Foo Task"                                #
  u.description "A small task description"
  u.done false
  u.pinned false
  u.confidentiality ""
end
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are several answers to this:

1) You may have a leaking spec that runs before this spec (this means that a task is created with the id and type of 'another_user' before this

2) It may be necessary to create the tasks, too (try to use Factory.create(:task) instead of just Factory(:task)

3) You may want to check out [shoulda](https://github.com/thoughtbot/shoulda), it helps you spec associations very easily, like this for example:

it { should have_many(:posts) }

Comment: The leaking spec seems outright impossible (the link is on id, the item is just created, ...), and there is no difference between `Factory.create(:task)` and `Factory(:task)`. But Shoulda is indeed a  good tip!

Comment: Thx for the answer, i'm using mongo and i've looked after shoulda, i can't use it for checking associations. However, i'm gonna try the other things you said.

Comment: @nathanvda there is a big difference between Factory.create and just calling Factory. The first goes to the db and the other does not.

Comment: @Pierre sorry for the late answer. My suggestion is that you should try to debug that with ruby debug / look up in the db what is actually created with which polymorphic owner_id and owner_type. A wild guess would be, that @user & another_user are somehow the same. Another suggestion concerning your factories: You don't have to explicitly assign nil values (unless your overwriting a default), at least it's like this on sql

Comment: @MilesRichard that is just plain wrong. `Factory(:task)` is just a shortcut to `Factory.create(:task)`.

Comment: @nathanvda in factory girl 1.2.3 it works like that. `thing = Factory(:thing); thing2 = Factory.create(:thing); ActiveRecord::Base.connection.select_all("SELECT * FROM things").size => 1.` It may have changed in newer versions though.

Answer (score 0):

That is pretty mind-numbing indeed. I see a few options to help you find this:

- use Rubymine, where you can easily debug your tests
- add a lot of log-statements
- add the following test:

  another_user.tasks.should =~ [task1, task2]

This will show the difference in the list of items, and will the other item be `task3` ?

- i hope your factory does not create a default task for each user?

Aside of that: indeed, checkout [shoulda](https://github.com/thoughtbot/shoulda)!